# How to do matrix-wise multiply in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I would appreciate some help with the following:

Given two tensors of

A = bsz x a_len x dim

B = bsz x b_len x dim

I would like to do a matrix-wise element-wise multiply such that each vector of length dim is multiplied with each vector (dim length) of B

The output should be:

bsz x a_len x b_len x dim

How can I do this in Tensorflow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at tf.einsum?

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/einsum

Does `tf.einsum('abd,acd->abcd', A, B)` give you what you're looking for?